# mascara para hora 24:00h

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Boa noite pessoal.

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para um problema. Tenho um campo no meu formulário pra receber hora.
Porém o que eu encontrei poucos validam. A maioria faz assim:
Ao digitar 24:00 transforma para 00:00 ... porém é isso que quero evitar.
No meu campo eu preciso colocar 24:00... seria 23:59 24:00 agora se eu digitar 24:01 ai sim teria que ficar 00:01...
Vocês tem alguma dica de como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Está usando `<input type="date">` ou algo diferente? Não tenho certeza se tem a ver com bootstrap

Comment: Qual o motivo pra isso, porque isso que você não quer é o comportamento correto 23:59 depois 00:00?

Comment: Os dois formatos estão corretos, mas 00:00 é preferível ao invés do 24:00. Vou responder me baseando no `<input type="date">`, outros componentes certamente se baseiam nos mesmos drafts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times), que é uma norma internacional para representação de data e hora, as duas representações estão corretas: 24:00 e 00:00. Mas a [W3C define](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value) que o elemento `<input>` do tipo `date` deve aceitar a data no formato especificado pelo [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), onde consta:

> Apesar da ISO 8601 permitir que a hora seja "24", esse *perfil* da ISO 8601 permite apenas valores entre "00" e "23" para a hora, com o intuito de diminuir confusão.

Não é só o RFC 3339 que desencoraja a forma "24:00" – manuais de de estilo e regulamentos militares em alguns países também desaconselham o uso. O manual para a Marinha dos EUA e o Corpo de Fuzileiros Navais dos EUA formalmente especifica como valores válidos de 0001 a 2359. ([Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00))

Apesar de ser possível fazer um componente que aceite o valor 24:00, não vejo muita vantagem em tanto trabalho pra formatar a data num formato despadronizado.